# what is the use of done: false mean in mongoose while creating the model?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Here `done:false` is used in the below code, what does it function here?it is present in my comment line.

```
 Review.create({
            title : req.body.title,
            description : req.body.description,
            rating: req.body.rating,
            done : false     //what does it mean???
        }, function(err, review) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);
```

Answer (score 0):

It just means that your new document will have a field with "done" as key and "false" boolean as value.

Comment: but what is the use of this?

Comment: It is your code...  
You should better than me know why you need this field...  
It does not mean anything regarding MongoDB, this field is used by the application I guess.

Comment: OK so it is useless, you can remove it :-)